# Autentificar a un usuario con certificado digital con Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, autenticación, ssl

Necesito que cuando un usuario ingrese en mi página web, busque un certificado para loguearlo automáticamente con Laravel, pero no encuentro mucha información de cómo configurarlo para que te pida un certificado.
El fin es que cuando un usuario pase su dni por el lecto de DNI, éste se loguee automáticamente.

Cualquier información la agradezco. Gracias!

Comment: Imagino que el certificado lo quieres usar para identificador al emisor de la llamada, pero si solo es para identificar al usuario podrías hacer un match entre el número  de DNI y el usuario de tu bd (o crear un nuevo usuario) y luego de eso loguearlo.

Comment: Claro.. no me vale solo con el número del DNI, es algo más complicado tiene que ser mediante un certificado que el usuario tenga instalado en su navegador. He encontrado esto pero no sé si me sirve exactamente.. https://github.com/metaclassing/PHP7-Laravel5-EnterpriseAuth/blob/master/src/Controllers/AuthController.php#L120-L133